# MySQL Joining ON column a IN (column b)

Tags: mysql, join

Hi I'm wondering if it is possible to do something like below. Obviously I've tried to run this in phpMyAdmin but there is an error. Perhaps there is another way to write this query.

```
SELECT * FROM eat_eat_restaurants AS r 
INNER JOIN eat_eat_cuisines AS c ON c.cuisine_id IN (r.cuisine_ids)
```

Further to this is it possible to select the restaurant name and cuisines in one row? e.g.

```
r_name    c_names
Marco's   Italian, Modern European
```

My 2 tables look like so:

```
TABLE EAT_EAT_RESTAURANTS
id  r_name    cuisine_ids
1   Marco's   1,2
2   Beldaro   3,4
3   Benny's   1,3


TABLE EAT_EAT_CUISINES
id  c_name
1   Italian
2   Modern European
3   Greek
4   Belgian
5   ...
```

Comment: YOu shot yourself in the foot by storing `cuisine_ids` as a comma delimited list. You should use an intermediate table for such m-to-n relations. For second part of your question: GROUP_CONCAT()

Comment: Thanks, not shot in the foot yet, still in design process - so glad to have the help of you guys on stackoverflow!

Comment: Ahh. Good to see someone asking which side should be pointed away before pulling the trigger :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current schema is not normalized and very inefficient. Try 3 tables: `restaurants`, `cuisines` and `restaurant_cuisines` and do the query like this:

```
SELECT r.r_name, GROUP_CONCAT(c.c_name)
FROM restaurants r JOIN restaurant_cuisines rc ON (r.id=rc.r_id)
 JOIN cuisines c ON (rc.c_id=c.id)
GROUP BY r.r_name;
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip I have done this and it works. Please fix an error in your answer though for the benefit of future visitors - rs.r_id -> rc.r_id and rs.c_id -> rc.c_id. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

No, the syntax doesn't work like that.

What you need to do is create a cross-table between the Restaurants and Cuisines, since a Cuisine can belong to multiple Restaurants and a Restaurant offers multiple Cuisines. After that, you can JOIN the three tables together to get the name of the Restaurant as well as all the names of the Cuisines they offer.

The cross table would have fields like this:

```
id   restaurant_id   cuisine_id
1    1               1
2    1               2
3    2               1
4    2               3
5    4               1
```

Answer (score 1):

need third table:

```
TABLE EAT_EAT_CUISINES_LOOKUP
r_id    cuisine_ids 1   
1       1
1       2 
// for Marco
```

next JOIN to it, if results in 1 line needed use GROUP_CONCAT()

Answer (score 0):

As an other solution I would recommend to use a join table which makes your query simple.
Let's name it: restaurant_cuisine
An example:

```
Id restaurant_id cuisine_id
1        1          1
1        1          2
```